# How to display the input of those expectations which were wrong?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I am testing a static class method, passing many different inputs into it. Since each input is quite big, I saved the list somewhere and pass each to the method in a loop.

However I realize that the errors does not display the input to these methods, making it difficult to debug. Is there a way to display this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could label the inputs (e.g. in an hash) and use the labels to create the example titles, so that you know which input produced the unexpected results?

E.g.

```
INPUTS = {
  "returns an error when input is too big" => { :input => ..., :output => ... },
  "returns an error when input too small" => { :input => ..., :output => ... },
  "returns a pony when input is just right" => { :input => ..., :output => ... },
}

INPUTS.each do |title, bundle|
  it title do
    StaticClass.method(bundle[:input]).should == bundle[:output]
  end
end
```

This example is silly; obviously, you'd want to load your data out of yaml files or whatever, but I was too lazy to pop demo code for that.  Dir.glob.somethingorother. :-)

Also, note that the problem you're trying to solve is an inherent problem in fixture-driven tests; you have to look somewhere outside the example code to see what the example code was doing. If you can avoid fixture-driven tests, I recommend that you do so.